# Search in list string element by value

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is list in which the string line, how to search for the presence of value in the list?
example value 'print'

```
tlist = ['Hello world',
       'Hello world print',
       'Text',
       'World hello print']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tlist = ['Hello world',
   'Hello world print',
   'Text',
   'World hello print']

print [i for i in tlist if "print" in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in tlist:
    if 'print' in i:
         print '"print" is in the line"'
```